# Custom Error Message in HTML Form

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to set a custom error message in an HTML5 form with the `required` attribute, however it doesn't appear to be working.

Code:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
    <input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
    <textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Contact Me" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" />             
</form>
<script>
    var name = document.querySelector( "#name" );
    function setErrorMessage() {
        if ( name.validity.valueMissing ) {
            name.setCustomValidity( "Please enter your name" );
        }
    };
setErrorMessage();
name.addEventListener( "change", setErrorMessage );
 </script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4eutova/1/

I've looked round and I thought the syntax was correct, but it doesn't appear to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind--I found and am using this solution: https://github.com/javanto/civem.js

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and understand the problem, you aren't calling the function setErrorMessage() anywhere. You need to add `onClick="setErrorMessage()` in your submit button input description.

Also, I would try changing the code to use `document.getElementById("_your_object_id_");` instead. Or getElementsByName().